# Auth Provider Callback masking ErrorDescription

Tags: error, authentication, auth-provider, callback, azure

we have Azure as Auth Provider for our community users. For some reason whenever Auth flow is interrupted in Azure, SF masks result in callback call and error_description is removed.
Because of this, we are unable to differentiate between clicks on Forgotten Password or Cancel.

When user clicks on any of these buttons, Azure redirects user to correct callback URL with proper params:

```
.../services/authcallback/AuthProviderName?error=access_denied&error_description=AADB2C90091%3a+The+user+has+cancelled+entering+self-asserted+information...
```

error_description (code) is specific for the action.

When authcallback handles request and determines that it is an error, it redirects this request to error handler. But error_description is not longer available. it is masked with same dummy value regardless of original response:

```
.../s/errorhandler?ErrorCode=Remote_Error&ErrorDescription=access_denied...
```

Is there some way to stop SF from masking this information?

Or are we doing something wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion with Salesforce support agent, IDEA was created: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V0000015LKoQAM vote if you want this feature.